# $L^1$ function is bounded almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Suppose $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Is it true that $f$ is bounded (except for a set of measure zero)?

I think it should be true, but can't show it formally. If $f$ is unbounded, why would we have $\int_\mathbb{R}|f|dx=\infty$?

Comment: @T.Bongers But isn't that unbounded near zero?

Comment: Yes, but it's still $L^1$.

Comment: Yes it is. That's what you were looking for.

Comment: Wait, that function is not in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, is it?

Comment: @T.Bongers I'm pretty sure $|x|^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is not $L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every measurable function is "approximately continuous" almost everywhere. See https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Approximate_continuity. In view of the examples  you are given in the comment, this is the best you can hope for.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a counter example : take the function $f$ defined by $f=0$ on $(-\infty,1]$, $f(n)=n$ for integers $n\ge 2$ , $f\left(n-\frac{1}{n^3}\right)=0=f\left(n+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$, $f$ is piecewise affine on $\left[ n-\frac{1}{n^3},n+\frac{1}{n^3} \right]$ and $f$ is zero elsewhere. $f$ is clearly unbounded, non-negative and you can easily compute its integral and see (thanks to the fact that $\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$) that $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Why do you need $\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$? You are using the Lebesgue measure not the counting measure.

Answer (score 3):

What about $x^{\alpha}$ on $(0,1]$ for some $\alpha> -1$?